# Ignore specific annotation in jackson

Tags: jackson

I want to Ignore a specific annotation when using Jackson programatically. I have tried to create my own AnnotationIntrospector by owerriding JacksonAnnotationIntrospector but I don't quite know how I can ignore a specific Annotation. The annotations I want to ignore are Deserialization annotations on my classes.